# How to include PECL extension in Yii console application

Tags: yii, console-application, v8

I installed PECL extension v8js and it works in normal mode in Yii. But I want to use in my console application, and it shows an error:

```
PHP Error[2]: include(V8Js.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please show the code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the php.ini that PHP uses when run from the console. You've most likely not enabled the extension there because PHP uses different configurations for web and CLI